# Ajax query throws server error 500 if over 16384 bytes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting Server error 500 when updating pages in Wordpress as soon as content length goes over 16384 bytes, regardless of the editor used (built in or Elementor). This only started after updating PHP from 7.4 to 8.2.6. It fails on Ajax POST query.

I've recreated all php.ini settings then also increased them significantly:

```
max_input_time: 600, 
max_input_vars: 500000, 
max_multipart_body_parts: 150000, 
output_buffering: 32096, 
memory_limit: 768M, 
upload_max_filesize: 32M, 
post_max_size: 32M, 
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS: 100000
```

mysqlnd Command buffer size: 32768, Read buffer size: 32768.

Database extension mysqli > innodb_buffer_pool_size: 134217728 (~128 MB) > key_buffer_size: 8388608 (~8 MB), max_allowed_packet: 134217728 (~128 MB).

I also tried increasing

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen="1073741824", 
maxAllowedContentLength="300000000", 
maxUrl="409600", 
maxQueryString="204800", 
maxJsonLength="50000000"
```

in web.config.

It is Wordpress 6.2, MySQL 8.0.19 on IIS 10.

Interestingly 16384 is 4x4096 exactly. There were some 4096 values in config files which I increased significantly in the settings. 1 character over 16384 and it fails. Nothing useful is logged in php logs. This is a relatively small page with a few paragraphs of text.

I've spent days troubleshooting this. Any help would be endlessly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, step 1. STOP with the scatter gun approach to probelm solving! 2. Find the error log and show us the actual FULL error message

Comment: `memory_limit:` is the most likely param involved in this as it seems likely this is an array using a lot of memory. However, 768M is pretty near HUGE, so if you are exceeding that, the code may be at fault. Alternatively, maybe you didnt change the correct `php.ini` file. Did you try and check using a quick `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` script